# User authentication and session logging with Google Cloud

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using Google Application Engine to host a web application and Google Cloud Storage to host documents.

I would like to keep track of:

- User authentication (performed via OAuth);
- User token expiration (to keep track of the active sessions);
- User interaction with the storage API to monitor their actions.

Is it possible to tune Stackdriver for this purposes? And how? Is there a specific guide I can follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a look at [Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/).
Basically with IAP you should be able to control all the accesses to your application deployed within GCP. You can then tune your logging scope as described as follows: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/audit-log-howto.

---

*Disclaimer: Comments and opinions are my own and not the views of my employer.*

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are Data Access audit logs that record user-provided data, however, these are disabled by default because of their sizes. You can enable these logs following the steps explained in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access). Please note that additional costs might be incurred because of these logs.

For more information about the Data Access logs, you can read these [articles](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#data-access) [as well](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#user_identities_in_audit_logs).